# How to set STEP(AWS::EMR::Step) priority in CloudFormation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation template I am creating an EMR cluster and have added 2 Hive steps using AWS::EMR::Step resource.

1. First step contain - HIVE DDL statement
2. Second Step contains - HIVE DML statement

I am creating Stack by passing CloudFormation template to it. But while EMR creation, many times second step executes first having all DML statements and it fails since DB & table schema is not present.

I want to set priority so that everytime HIVE DDL step executes first.
Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DependsOn` property in your Cloudformation template to order your EMR steps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to set priority on EMR STEP API. So, CloudFormation will not able to have that feature.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_RunJobFlow.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_StepConfig.html

Since the HQL script run sequentially, you might rather have both DDL and DML statements in same script and run it in one STEP.